# Find admin login of webpages

Tags: web-application

I'm not able to find admin login page while pentest. **How to find admin login of webpages**?

`http://example.com/admin`, `http://example.com/wp-admin` returns 403 forbidden or 404 errors.

What to do in those cases ?

Comment: providing more details would be helpful. Are you trying to find the admin page for one website or multiple? What platform are they running? What methods have you already tried? Tools?

Answer (score 6):

1. Try to figure out what software is being used. Most applications have a default admin location (eg WordPress has multiple paths which work: `wp-admin`, `admin`, `login`, `wp-login.php`).
2. Check if the login page is linked from the website itself.
3. Try common paths, such as `admin`, `login`, etc. Note that access may be restricted by IP, so you may get a 403 or 404 even though you guessed the correct path.
4. Ask the admin. Even for a blackbox test, this is information that may be supplied.

Answer (score 2):

hi you can test this python script to search for admin page

https://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/UNIX/utilities/AdminpageFinder.py.txt

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!  Can you summarize how this works?  We don't want to be just a link farm, and we'd prefer answers that will remain useful even if the link stops working.

Comment: Ok sorry guys, this is just a python script that try a lot of known uri from a choose website. You can choose if you want test for php or other language. It is just for testing because this is not quite for ids , too much tests in same time.

Comment: please edit your post with these details

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods for this purpose.

1. ADDING URL

This is the first and easiest method to find website admin panel or admin login page. You can add some words after the URL.Like

www.site.com/admin

www.site.com/administrator

www.site.com/login

www.site.com/wp-login.php

www.site.com/admin.php

2. USING VARIOUS SCRIPT

You can use various scripts like various website admin panel finder to get the admin page. Here I am showing you an useful script which will help you to get the admin page. To run this script you first need to install Active Perl.get it from

http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

Now copy the code of http://pastebin.com/WWZszURW and save it as anything.pl and run the script to get the login page of the desired site.(Remember its a python Script).

The Perl Script will help you to find admin page of any site.

3. CRAWLING SOFTWARE

You can use various crawling tool to crawl the website and get the login page. These website crawl all the pages of the website and show the list of all pages and directories. For example; dirbuster.

4. USING ONLINE ADMIN FINDER OR SCANNER

There are many such online website admin panel finder available will help you in finding admin login page online.

I hope, this will can help you.